# TWIML with url attribute on Number not called

Tags: node.js, twilio

so I create an outbound call with `makeCall` which allows you to specify a url that that twilio will use when placing the call. That part works, twilio uses the URL specified in `makeCall` and calls my server. Now, I respond with a TWIML as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number url="SOME_VALID_URL" method="POST">
      SOME_E_164_NUMBER
    </Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

According to the Twilio documentation for [Number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number), this should work. My test server never sees the call from Twilio specified by the url param in `Number`. What should happen is that the attribute `url` above embedded in the `Number` tag should be called by Twilio after the TWIML gets passed back to them. That doesn't seem to be the case.

I am using ngrok to talk to my local server and it does work. That is not the problem. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is test server url is publicly accessible?

Comment: What do you want the Twilio to do by returning this TwiML ?

Comment: Are you using the full ngrok URL in the `url` attribute?